# how to make complete 100% row(device width) inside col-lg-3 using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[here i have 2 scenarios, 1) first is image one. there i have 4 cards in a each row(that will change based on screen size 4->2->1). it is in respective classes like col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12,  i have only one html markup to render the card, many cards are displaying dynamically based on back end data.

2) on clicking button in a each card, their respective extra details will come up in bottom to that in complete row.

here problem is since it is in column class, that extra details occupying only that much space(like parent div), i want that in single row. 1)https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8xEC.jpg 2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ewg.jpg]1

Comment: I guess you just have to put the detail markup outside the col/row of the card.
this could also be achieved by javascript click handler copying the hidden detail markup (inside the card) into a new container just below the current row. I can post an example if you want

Comment: yes, please. that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

because it's too long, i created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxyud676/1/

I'm not too happy with that solution, as it is not responsive.
my first thought was to just use the bootstrap collapsable features to use the cards as collapsible triggers, and place the preview markup outside the rows.
but this approach would open the preview on a xs screen always below the 4th element:

```
CARD 1
CARD 2   <-- clicking
CARD 3
CARD 4
PREVIEW for 2
CARD 5
CARD 6
...
```

my fiddle solution was then to detect the screen size (hence the number of used cols) and to move the preview markup to the correct position.
another way could be to duplicate the preview markup on the correct positions (for card 1 there is the preview with class "col-xs-12 visible-xs" just after the card, and the same object with "col-sm-6 col-md-6 visible-sm visible-md" after an evenly positioned card and with "visible-lg" after the current row)

it's more complicated than I initially thought :-/

Comment: thanks for your help, norganos. i'm checking the code.